# How do you destroy a block using Commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make a command block destroy some glowstone?

Comment: Have you researched your problem at all before coming to us and asking us to write a command for you?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `/setblock` command to replace the block with Air.

*Example:*

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> minecraft:air destroy
```

Where `<x>`, `<y>` and `<z>` are the coordinates of the block you want to replace. `destroy` is an optional parameter that determines how the block is broken, in this case meaning that the block that was there would be destroyed as if it was destroyed by a player.

More information on the `setblock` command can be found here: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock)